# Yii 2 + CKEditror + KCFinder

Tags: php, yii2, ckeditor

Доброго. Подскажите такой момент.
Прикрепляю я значит плагины, но не выходит. Задача сменить папку по умолчанию. Делаю так

```
'uploadURL' => '/upload/',
'uploadDir' => Yii::getAlias('@webroot').'/upload/',
'types' => [
    '' => '',
],
```

в итоге он не ходит по папкам и не грузит файлы. 
при выборе папки на сервер уходит: **dir: /upload/objects**

в итоге плагин генерирует такой путь:
**/var/www/main/www/mysite/upload/upload/objects**
и как следствие ничего не открывает.

уже устал гуглить, не нашел как задать ему свои пути и чтоб работало.
спасибо.